# Backup Script - Recursion

Tags: linux, cron, centos

We're looking to use the following backup script to move through each directory in the datavol folder yet it seems to fail on line 4.  If anyone has better suggestions on ways to do this, feel free to let me know.

```
for d in /home/datavol/ ; do
echo "$d"

tar -czf /backups/emalee-backup-$d-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz /home/datavol/$d

scp -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa_backup /backups/emalee-backup-$d-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz emalee-backup@peg.trinix.co:/home/emalee-backup/docker-backup

curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"channel": "#server","text": "We are all backed up. Good ol Emalee is safe on /"$d/". :pride:"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/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

rm /backups/emalee-backup-$d-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz -f

ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa_backup emalee-backup@peg.trinix.co

find /home/emalee-backup/docker-backup/ -mtime +7 -exec rm -f {} \;

TODAYSDATE=$(date +%d)
if [ "$TODAYSDATE" == "01" ] ;
then
    cp /home/emalee-backup/docker-backup/emalee-backup-$d-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz /home/emalee-backup/monthly-docker-backup/emalee-backup-$d-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz
    curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"channel": "#server","text": "Archived a monthly backup for good ol Emalee on $d. :handbag:"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/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
fi
done

logout
```

Comment: Look at your terminal, when `echo "$d"`

Comment: This is definitely not [tag:batch-file]-related (read the tag info)!

Answer (score 1):

Working Solution

```
for d in /home/datavol/hosts/* ; do

s="${d##*/}"

echo "$s"

tar -czf /backups/emalee-backup-$s-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz $d

scp -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa_backup /backups/emalee-backup-$s-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz emalee-backup@peg.trinix.co:/home/emalee-backup/docker-backup

curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"channel": "#server","text": "We are all backed up. Good ol Emalee is safe on "'"$s"'". :pride:"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/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

rm /backups/emalee-backup-$s-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz -f

done
```